# Faster finding of rows in matlab

Tags: matlab, search, mex

I have a very long list of x,y,z coordinates of items (200K-800K,3) that I need to search through and find the nearest items to a particular point - This final list is always has at least 1 item and usually less than 10 items.

I've tried a few simple search methods to find this list but I've hit a bit of a limit - here are my two best methods to date:

#### Method 1 - find Indexing

```
xInd = find(PositionsList(:,1) > (searchPoint(i,1) - searchRad) & PositionsList(:,1) < (searchPoint(i,1) + searchRad));
yInd = find(PositionsList(xInd,2) > (searchPoint(i,2) - searchRad) & PositionsList(xInd,2) < (searchPoint(i,2) + searchRad));
xyInd = xInd(yInd);
zInd = find(PositionsList(xyInd,3) > (searchPoint(i,3) - searchRad) & PositionsList(xyInd,3) < (searchPoint(i,3) + searchRad));
xyzInd = xyInd(zInd);
```

#### Method 2 - Brute force distance search

```
neighbours = sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus,searchPoint(i,:),PositionsList).^2,2)) <= searchRad;
xyzInd = find(neighbours == 1);
```

#### Method 3 - logial Indexing

```
xInd = PositionsList(:,1) > (searchPoint(i,1) - searchRad) & PositionsList(:,1) < (searchPoint(i,1) + searchRad);
newlist = PositionsList(xInd==1,:);
yzInd = newlist(:,2) > (searchPoint(i,2) - searchRad) & newlist(:,2) < (searchPoint(i,2) + searchRad)... 
    & newlist(:,3) > (searchPoint(i,3) - searchRad) & newlist(:,3) < (searchPoint(i,3) + searchRad);
xyzInd = newlist(yzInd==1,:);
```

For my data method 1 is much quicker - for a small list of 20000 particles it runs in about 25s whereas method 2 runs in about 170s, but method 2 is slightly more accurate - it has dubious neighbours (outlier on edge of search area) much less often.

My code calls this search several thousand times so I'm keen to save as much time on it as possible - it currently makes up about 85% of my run-time. I've read that mex implementation may be much quicker but I'm not familiar mex. I've also tried a 3rd method of logical indexing rather than find, but it is slower at 35s.

Can someone help with making this search faster? Maybe a mex function?

Comment: You could be interested by a k-d tree check this link: [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) (especially the point 2.1 and 2.5)

Comment: Ho and If you have the Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox , a kd tree function is already implemented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from obchardon suggestion I had a look at k-d trees for searching and found the following, [kd-tree for matlab](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21512-kd-tree-for-matlab), on file exchange with my data and began testing with my data. 
Now I can complete a search in under 5s for 500K coordinates, compared with my previous best of 25s for 20K sets of coordinates. Huge improvement.

The only down side is the order it returns the neighbours seems to be random which mean I have some slight "caressing" of the results to do, but with the time saved, this is more than acceptable.

Thanks for the great suggestion!!